# Can wizarding students skip classes/grades/years?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, wizards, witches

In America at least, if a grade school student (K - 12) is exceptionally gifted they are allowed to advance to a higher learning level without having to take the previous courses, up to and including entire years.

**Has this ever happened in the wizarding world at *any* school?**

As far as Hogwarts goes, Hermione would have been a good candidate, but I don't think she ever skipped ahead at all. Riddle and Dumbledore would also have had the capability, but I'm pretty sure Riddle went through all seven years' classes. I don't know Dumble's history.

Again, I'm asking about *any and all* of the wizarding schools in the world. Whether any student has ever been able to *skip a whole year* or even *a couple classes* due to their talent.

Comment: Not a full answer, but Ron and Harry went on to become Aurors (aka, requiring higher schooling) without ever taking a seventh year at Hogwarts, so that's similar.

Comment: Dumbledore didn't skip I think we can be fairly confident of that from Doge's testimony

Comment: @Au101 Maybe it's an American thing

Comment: It does happen but is very rare in the UK.

Comment: Hermione did not skip. In fact, so dedicated was she to her studies, that after the events of Book 7 she went back to Hogwarts and finished her N.E.W.Ts, whilst Harry and Ron went with Kingsley Shacklebolt to become Aurors. Incidentally, the Aurors' office deliberately relaxed their entry requirements in order to allow Harry and Ron to join.

Comment: As Bellerophon says, it's a very rare occurrence in the UK. The more preferred practice is simply teach the gifted students a more advanced curriculum, but keep them within the same class. This allows them to both learn at their own pace and maintain their friendships within the class.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - and ensure that skipping doesn't leave gaps in their knowledge. Skipping can easily result in, well, skipping things!

Answer (score 3):

There is still frustratingly little information about the other Schools.

There is some subtle magic in being educated for 7 years at Hogwarts. It wasn't explicitly written by JKR. However it seems to be heavily implied. Even if students don't get many O.W.Ls, they would still carry on with what would remain of their courses. As was the case with Fred and George before they left of their own accord. So it seems as if there is heavy importance in keeping students there for all seven years.

While not really skipping, I think Hermione being authorized for a Time-Turner in her third year is as close as you can get.

Comment: What is this subtle magic of which you speak?

Comment: The subtle magic of 7? It's under the umbrella of arithmancy. It occurs very frequently throughout Harry Potter that calling it subtle might not even be accurate. 7 is the normal age in which magic manifests itself in witches and wizards. 7 years is the duration of magical education. Voldemort wanted to split his soul 7 times because it's "the most magically powerful number"

Answer (score 3):

One could argue that Dennis Creevey might have skipped a year. As I pointed out [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/194051/100430), Dennis Creevey started Hogwarts in *Goblet of Fire*, yet one year later he was in Hogsmeade for the first D.A. meeting, even though Hogsmeade is only open to third years and above.

One way to explain Dennis's presence in Hogsmeade would be that he actually was in **third** year in *Order of the Phoenix*, because he skipped a year. This would also explain how he was able to participate in a magic club in which every other member was in fourth year or above — you would not expect an average second year student to be able to keep up.

Comment: that was an excellent example! +1