# How did Dennis Creevey get into Hogsmeade?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Goblet of Fire* Chapter 12 we see that Dennis Creevey starts at Hogwarts that year:

> “Hiya, Harry!”
>
> It was Colin Creevey, a third year to whom Harry was  something of a
> hero.
>
> “Hi, Colin,” said Harry warily.
>
> “Harry, guess what? Guess what, Harry? My brother’s starting! My
> brother Dennis!”

By all accounts, then, in *Order of the Phoenix* (one year later) he should be in his second year. Yet in Chapter 16 of *Order of the Phoenix* we find him in Hogsmeade for the first D.A. meeting (my emphasis):

> First came Neville with Dean and Lavender, who were  closely followed
> by Parvati and Padma Patil with  (Harry’s stomach did a back flip) Cho
> and one of her  usually giggling girlfriends, then (on her own and
> looking so dreamy that she might have walked in by  accident) Luna
> Lovegood; then Katie Bell, Alicia  Spinnet, and Angelina Johnson,
> Colin and **Dennis  Creevey**, Ernie Macmillan, Justin
> Finch-Fletchley,  Hannah Abbott, and a Hufflepuff girl with a long
> plait  down her back whose name Harry did not know; three Ravenclaw
> boys he was pretty sure were called Anthony Goldstein, Michael Corner,
> and Terry Boot;  Ginny, followed by a tall skinny blond boy with an
> upturned nose whom Harry recognized vaguely as  being a member of the
> Hufflepuff Quidditch team, and  bringing up the rear, Fred and George
> Weasley with  their friend Lee Jordan, all three of whom were
> carrying large paper bags crammed with Zonko’s  merchandise.

We know from *Prisoner of Azkaban* Chapter 1 that Hogsemeade is only permitted to third years and above (my emphasis):

> *Dear Mr. Potter,*
>
> *Please note that the new school year will begin on
> September the first. The Hogwarts Express will leave from King’s Cross
> station, platform nine and three-  quarters, at eleven o’clock.*
>
> ***Third years are permitted to visit the village of  Hogsmeade on certain
>
> weekends.** Please give the  enclosed permission form to your
> parent or guardian to  sign.*
>
> *A list of books for next year is
> enclosed.*
>
> *Yours sincerely,*
>
> *Professor M. McGonagall*
>
> *Deputy Headmistress*

We also know from *Order of the Phoenix* Chapter 16 that Filch was checking the permission status of everyone leaving the castle *for that very Hogsmeade visit*:

> The morning of the Hogsmeade visit dawned bright  but windy. After
> breakfast they queued up in front of  Filch, who matched their names
> to the long list of  students who had permission from their parents or
> guardian to visit the village.

How, then, was Dennis Creevey able to get into Hogsmeade, considering he would have only been a second year?

Comment: Excellent question! Never noticed that before. Sounds like a prime case of Rowling Maths.

Comment: Colin was good at sneaking (not that it ended well for him), so maybe it runs in the family.

Comment: I had realized this before but forgotten about it! Hope you find an answer!

Comment: Sounds like he snuck out of Hogwarts through a plothole

Comment: The visit to Hogsmeade by Dennis Creevey was a clandestine one and not an academic regular one, which means that he managed to reach the Hog's Head Inn with the rest of the group, illegally. How he did it? I couldn’t find any record about it at Tomes and Scrolls. I can only guess things like his brother Colin may have used an Impediment Jinx to freeze the great black dog that bounds up the streets in Hogsmeade to let Dennis slip in the Village.

Answer (score 3):

Several possibilities, though not so compelling:

1. Perhaps the third year rule had been changed. While in *Prisoner of Azkaban* it is clear that only third years and above can visit Hogsmeade, and Dumbledore reiterates this in *Goblet of Fire*<sup>1</sup>, there does not appear to be any mention of this rule in *Order of the Phoenix* or *Half-Blood Prince*. Perhaps the rule had been changed, and anyone with permission from a parent/guardian could go, regardless of year.
2. Perhaps Dennis had skipped a year, and was thus already a third year in *Order of the Phoenix* despite it being only his second year of school. One could perhaps argue that he was exceptionally advanced for his age. After all, with only one year of magical training he is part of a magic club where everyone else has three to six years of magical training.
3. Perhaps he illegally snuck out through one of the secret passages that Filch wasn't monitoring. While this would be the simplest answer, we do not find Dennis making any effort to stay hidden (as Harry used to do when there illegally), and no one else seems to have cared that he was there. Moreover, when Umbridge found the list of D.A. members and was accusing them of illegal activity, she surely would have mentioned that one of the students was not allowed to be in Hogsmeade in the first place (unless she didn't notice Dennis's name).

---

<sup>1. In his announcement at the start-of-term feast:</sup>

> <sup>The corners of Dumbledore's mouth twitched. He continued, "As ever, I
>   would like to remind you all that the forest on the grounds is
>   out-of-bounds to students, as is the village of Hogsmeade to all below
>   third year.</sup>

Comment: While point 2 is possible, I think point 3 is trying too hard. Since the story is from Harry's POV, he might not know what Dennis had to do to get there. And as for Umbridge not calling him out--correct me if I'm wrong--but in the list of *illegal* things Umbridge had to go off of, breaking a school rule could easily get overlooked when compared to everything else.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd To clarify, you're not disagreeing with point 3; you're disagreeing with the *weakness* of point 3.

Comment: I'm disagreeing with the *strength*

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd My point about Umbridge was that it presents a weakness of the theory that Dennis illegally snuck in, because if he really had done so then Umbridge would have mentioned that. Your first comment seemed to be challenging that point. You argued that even if it had been illegal Umbridge would not have mentioned it. That sounds like you're refuting the potential weakness that I brought up.

Comment: Yes. The *weakness* of that part, but the overall *strength* of point 3 as a possibility. Like I said, that one seems too far of a stretch.